# Bootstrap Automatically Adjust Based on Screen Size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I create design interface for web using Bootstrap 3. If it shown in large screen size, it looks like this:

[image]

but, if it shown in small screen size, it looks like this:

[image]

I've problem when it will be shown in small screen size. The script what I've done in 
[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/RgOxbGKgBE) is not compatible in small size.

Comment: try this - http://www.bootply.com/render/r84RWMx5ah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to place your `label` tags with your `input` tags inside the same columns.

**[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/V5K3nM5wE4)**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <label>Label1</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="text1">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <label>Label2</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="text2">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <label>Label3</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="text3">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <label>Label4</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="text4">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm a little bit confused about grid system, now it's clear thanks

Comment: col-md-3 as a direct child of col-md-3 is incorrect; see https://github.com/twbs/bootlint/wiki/E014